# Multiple conditions on ngstyle

Tags: angularjs

I would like to if possible add multiple conditions to ng style

Currently I set the width and color like this

```
[ngStyle]="{
              'width': (question.score.toFixed(1) * 10)+'%', 
              'background-color': question.score.toFixed(1) < 3 ?'red' : '#00c9c7' 
              }"
```

However I want to score under 3 are red, and over 7 are green. This condition gives me under 3 are red, anything else is turquoise. Are you able to add multiple conditions to ng style?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I strongly advise to make a function in your js code to be called, instead of writing it inline.

But it would be:

```
question.score.toFixed(1) < 3 ? 'red' : question.score.toFixed(1) > 7 ? 'green' : '#00c9c7'
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful tip and the correct answer, will accept when I can

Comment: Are you able to add multiple conditions to multiple attributes?  I need to change my text color and background color based on a certain JSON value. I haven't found a a way to make that possible yet.